# Can I ask a question about a claim I don't remember where I read?

Tags: support, asking-questions

There is a claim that I read somewhere, but I am unable to find where I read it.

I distinctly remember what the claim is, but won't be able to cite the source.

Is such a question acceptable on this site?

Answer (score 7):

Historically, our position has been that there is just too much risk that the claim has been misremembered or misunderstood, and if we don't have a source to check, we can't address that.

Meanwhile, if it truly is widely believed, you should be able to find someone else making them claim.

If you can't, then what value is there in us spending the time to evaluate the claim?